# PDFBox - overlay content being rotated

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a pdf (the backing pdf) that has a page that is rotated (rotated to landscape).
I have an overlay pdf that has page with dimensions the same as the landscape page but it has no rotation.
When the overlay is applied, the overlay is being rendered perpendicular to the rotated page.
[image: example showing text rendered perpendicular]

I've attempted setting the rotation of the individual overlay pdf pages but it seems to have no effect.

```
    PDDocument baseDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("examples/test/base.pdf"));;
    PDDocument overlayDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("examples/test/overlay.pdf"));

    Iterator<PDPage> baseDocumentIterator = baseDocument.getPages().iterator();
    Iterator<PDPage> overlayIterator = overlayDocument.getPages().iterator();

    while(baseDocumentIterator.hasNext() && overlayIterator.hasNext()) {
        PDPage backing = baseDocumentIterator.next();
        PDPage foreground = overlayIterator.next();
        if(backing.getRotation()!= foreground.getRotation())
        {
            foreground.setRotation(-backing.getRotation()); //doesn't seem to do antyhing
        }
    }

    PDAcroForm acroForm = baseDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    if (acroForm != null) {
        acroForm.flatten();
    }
    Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
    overlay.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.FOREGROUND);
    overlay.setInputPDF(baseDocument);
    overlay.setAllPagesOverlayPDF(overlayDocument);

    Map<Integer, String> ovmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    overlay.overlay(ovmap);

    AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission();
    ap.setCanExtractContent(false);
    ap.setCanFillInForm(false);
    ap.setCanModify(false);
    ap.setReadOnly();
    ap.setCanModifyAnnotations(false);
    StandardProtectionPolicy standardPP = new StandardProtectionPolicy("", "", ap);
    standardPP.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
    baseDocument.protect(standardPP);
    baseDocument.save("examples/test/output.pdf");
    baseDocument.close();
    overlayDocument.close();
```

[Sample pdfs](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1l59aUPZtEJQmojVVe0HaR54M-m32Zicq)

Is there any way to handle this case with pdfbox?
Thanks

Comment: There is only one pdf on the link, overlay.pdf

Comment: @areus files updated.

Comment: which version of pdfbox are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are probably using a pdfbox version before 2.0.17 as in this version a bug that causes the described behavior was [fixed](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/www-announce/201909.mbox/%3Ce8ef46ec-63bb-1183-05d0-318138a269a3@apache.org%3E):

```
[PDFBOX-4596] - Overlays with /Rotate value appear rotated in result file
```

with 2.0.17 and later your code generates:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in PDFBOX. Overlay ignored rotated pages. You can see the issue here [PDFBOX-4596](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4596). It is resolved since version 2.0.17 released on 2019-09-20.

Also note that since version 2.0.10, you can override `Overlay.calculateAffineTransform` to have major control of how the overlay is applied (the default is to center on the destination)